# writing a fomatted tibble to a tsv in R

Tags: r, csv, format, tidyverse, tibble

The formatting tidyverse provides for tibbles is useful for displaying results in console.

How can I export the tibble formatting to a .txt or .csv file?

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df = replicate(n=5, rnorm(n=10))
tbl = as_tibble(df)
tbl = tbl %>% mutate(
  V1 = num( (abs(V1)/max(abs(V1))), label = "%", scale = 100, digits = 2, notation = "dec"), 
  V2 =  num(V2, digits = 1, notation = "dec"),
  V3 = num(V3, sigfig = 3, notation = "sci") )

out_path = getwd() # modify as needed

print(tbl, n=Inf, width = Inf)
# A tibble: 10 × 5
       V1        V2       V3      V4      V5
        % <dec:.1!>  <sci:3>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  32.68       1.2 -1.07e+0  0.426  -0.695 
 2  13.42       0.4 -2.18e-1 -0.295  -0.208 
 3  90.88       0.4 -1.03e+0  0.895  -1.27  
 4   4.11       0.1 -7.29e-1  0.878   2.17  
 5   7.54      -0.6 -6.25e-1  0.822   1.21  
 6 100.00       1.8 -1.69e+0  0.689  -1.12  
 7  26.87       0.5  8.38e-1  0.554  -0.403 
 8  73.76      -2.0  1.53e-1 -0.0619 -0.467 
 9  40.05       0.7 -1.14e+0 -0.306   0.780 
10  25.99      -0.5  1.25e+0 -0.380  -0.0834

tbl_out_fmt = <'some function'>
write_tsv(tbl_out_fmt, file = file.path(out_path, "tibble_example.txt") )
```

I would like to write the formatted version of the tibble, much as it appears with print(). Specifically, V1, V2, and V3 should be written as printed, whereas V4, and V5 should be written with the standard number of digits (more than are printed).

I don't particularly care whether or not the written file has the header `( % <dec:.1!>  <sci:3>   <dbl>   <dbl> )`, but it would be fine to include.

Comment: So what exactly do you want the output file to look like in this case? Can you show the desired output so we can verify possible solutions?

Comment: One kind of document are you including it in? There has been a lot of effort in things like `rmarkdown` and `stargazer` and `kableExtra` that format tables for docx, html, pdf formats that are publication-quality.

Comment: `s/^One/What/` (auto-type?)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to catpure the output of the print, you can use `capture.output` to set it to a file. Though you probably want to turn off the default terminal-escape coloring that happens by default. You can create a helper function for that

```
no_color_capture <- function(..., file=NULL) {
  opt <- options(crayon.enabled = FALSE)
  on.exit(options(opt))
  capture.output(..., file=file)
} 
no_color_capture(print(tbl, n=Inf, width = Inf), file=file.path(out_path, "tibble_example.txt"))
```

Comment: I would like a function that exports the formatting to tsv/csv though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does what I had in mind. Only problem is I don't like the fact that the print command which is used to obtain the formatted columns forces the whole tibble to output to console.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pillar)

set.seed(123)
df = replicate(n=5, rnorm(n=10))
tbl = as_tibble(df)
tbl = tbl %>% mutate(
  V1 = num( (abs(V1)/max(abs(V1))), label = "%", scale = 100, digits = 2, notation = "dec"),
  V2 = num(V2, digits = 2, notation = "dec"),
  V3 = num(V3, sigfig = 3, notation = "sci"),
  VA = letters[1:10])
sapply(tbl, class)
out_path = getwd() # modify as needed

get_tbl_fmt = function(tbl, max.digits = NULL, balance_negs = TRUE){
  
  # for the columns that were not formatted with pillar::num(), the digits will be set to max.digits.
  # if max.digits is not set, set to the max of the options "digits or "pillar.sigfig"
  if(is.null(max.digits)){ max.digits = max( unlist(options("digits", "pillar.sigfig")) )}
  
  opt <- options(pillar.print_max = Inf,     # print all rows
                 pillar.neg = FALSE,         # don't highlight negative numbers
                 pillar.sigfig = max.digits, # for columns without num() formatting, print more sigfigs (or less) than the default 3
                 pillar.subtle_num = FALSE,  # don't print fancy formatting (color/bold )
                 pillar.subtle = FALSE       # don't print fancy formatting (color/bold )
  )
  on.exit(options(opt))
  
  # convert num() formatted columns to character
  tbl = tbl %>% mutate(across(where(~class(.x)[1] == "pillar_num"), ~as.character(print(pillar_shaft(.x))) ))
  # convert additional numeric columns to character
  tbl = tbl %>% mutate(across(where(~class(.x)[1] == "numeric"),    ~as.character(print(pillar_shaft(  num(.x, digits = max.digits, notation = "dec") ))) ))
  # remove the pillar underlining characters (not available to shut off using pillar options)
  tbl = tbl %>% mutate(across(where(~class(.x)[1] == "character"),  ~gsub('\u001b\\[\\d*m', '', .x, perl = TRUE) ))
  if(balance_negs){
    # for those digits without leading negative signs, pad with a leading space
    tbl = tbl %>% mutate(across(where(~class(.x)[1] == "character" & any(grepl("^\\-", .x))),  ~ifelse(grepl("^\\-",.x), .x, paste0(" ", .x)) ))
  }
  tbl
}

# get formatted tbl as character vectors
tbl_out_fmt = get_tbl_fmt(tbl, max.digits = 10); tbl_out_fmt; tbl
# write to tsv:
write_tsv(tbl_out_fmt, file = file.path(out_path, "tbl_out_fmt"))
```